# сохранить фото после вызова imageIntent

Tags: java, android, изображения

Учусь использовать камеру в Android studio, научился запускать камеру и отображать миниатюру, а вот сохранить фото не получается, перепробовал несколько вариантов которые советуют в интернете. Вот код который есть сейчас

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "MyImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Выводим сообщение об ошибке
            String errorMessage = "Ваше устройство не поддерживает съемку";
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

но когда я нажимаю кнопку сфотографировать мое приложение просто закрывается, на телефоне SD карты нет вдруг это имеет значение

манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: https://www.zoftino.com/android-capture-image-from-camera-and-save

Comment: этот ресурс мне не помог

Comment: вы сказали что приложение просто закрывается, я допускаю что оно у вас вылетает, может есть ошибка?

Comment: при выполнении  startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0);
ошибка вот такая file:///Pictures/MyImages/image_001.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Comment: Добавил несколько строчек как посоветовали тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851566 приложение закрываться перестало но фото не сохраняется на телефон